# To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK

Tags: command-line, catalina

This seems to be a on-going thing with Apple but previous threads indicate that each time it seems to be a different issue. I just updated Catalina (10.15.7). The update included safari, system security update and a command-line tools update. After the update was complete, I get the following error when running `brew update`.

`To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK. Click "More info..." to visit the Java Developer Kit download website.`

When i click "more" it takes me to a [adobe flash player](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) end of life page. I noticed in similar threads it takes the user to a different page. For example in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267408/keep-getting-a-java-command-line-tool-notification-on-macos-sierra-10) it takes a user to a safari page. I don't have the facebook file in Library/LaunchAgents like what has been reported in similar threads from 2019.

Is "java" a dependency of command-line tools now? Can I resolve this message any other way besides trying to download JDK on a system that was running fine without it?

Why am i getting taken to an adobe flash page when i click more? I don't have flash either (unless it was installed by factory)

Comment: What is the URL given on more ? Have you installed any java or java dependent programs via brew

Comment: the url given on more is the one in the [post](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html). I asked in another thread [how to efficiently find if any package has a java dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139064/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-any-installed-brew-package-has-a-specific-dependency) because i'm not sure how to confirm that quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: PR was merged, fix will be available when version 3.0.1 is released.

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10491) that is being actively [worked on](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/10545).

I'm ignoring the alert for now, with the understanding that it will no longer show up once that PR is merged.